# What is wrong with this code

Tags: c

This is snippet of large code. I want to understand why `compare_int` is not getting proper pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int 
compare_int ( void *left, void *right ) {
    int *l = (int*)left;
    int *r = (int*)right;

    if ( *l < *r ) 
        return -1;
    else if ( *l > *r ) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    void *data1 = malloc ( sizeof ( int));
    int i = 55;
    memcpy ( data1, &i, sizeof(int));

    void *data2 = malloc ( sizeof ( int));
    int j = 65;
    memcpy ( data2, &j, sizeof(int));

    compare_int ( data1, data2 );


}
```

Comment: The function is called `compare_int`. Compare **int**. Why wouldn't you make its arguments integers?

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting proper pointers"?

Comment: Standard questions:  What result are you seeing?  What did you expect to happen?  How do these two outcomes differ?

Comment: Works fine for me. How do you know you're "not getting proper pointers" ?

Comment: Looks ok on first sight.  Did you try to run the code under a debugger?  And what do you mean with "not getting proper pointers"?

Comment: What's the actual problem? To met it looks like the values are beeing correctly passed to compare_int. However, there are some other issues (no need for pointers in compare_int for l and r). EDIT: Wow, everyone certainly jumped on this one.

Comment: Can you give some detail on what you are seeing?  What is the output of `compare_int()` when you run it?

Comment: **What is wrong with this code?**

There is nothing wrong with your code.<br>It is doing exactly what you wrote it to do.

What did you *intend* for it to do?  That may be different from what you wrote.<br> But we don't know what you intended, so we can only guess.

Comment: *l and *r does not give me integers, but it contain address.

Comment: @Avinash: And how are you coming to that conclusion?

Comment: I think the question here is how it can work with `void*` pointers instead of `int*` ?

Comment: @Muggen:  There's no problem with `void *` here.  The data is put in using `memcpy`, which works fine on `void *`, and the pointers are cast to `int *` in the function.  This looks like perfectly legal C to me, and that it will do the correct thing.

Comment: Works for me ... don't know what's wrong here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're struggling with. I'm going to interpret this question as why are

```
int *l = (int*)left;
int *r = (int*)right;
```

these lines necessary.

They're necessary because C is basically assembly. When you use a type in C, you're telling it how large you expect the field to be in terms of memory. The void type is exactly that - a type of totally undefined length. A void pointer is a pointer to a variable of *any* type. Actually, any pointer can point to any type, but when you dereference it you'll only read up to the size of that type.

Now the type `void` doesn't have a size. So you can't dereference a void pointer, because C doesn't know "where to stop" when reading the value.

So a good way to think of it is not `int* x` is a integer pointer but `x` is a pointer and the data it points to is an int of size 4 bytes (or whatever). By contrast `void* y` is a pointer and the data it points to is of unknown size and type.

A cast is used so that you know the size of the memory you're supposed to be reading once you've dereferenced your pointer.

See also the explanation from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/):

> ## void pointers
>
> The void type of pointer
>   is a special type of pointer. In C++,
>   void represents the absence of type,
>   so void pointers are pointers that
>   point to a value that has no type (and
>   thus also an undetermined length and
>   undetermined dereference properties).
>
> This allows void pointers to point to
>   any data type, from an integer value
>   or a float to a string of characters.
>   But in exchange they have a great
>   limitation: the data pointed by them
>   cannot be directly dereferenced (which
>   is logical, since we have no type to
>   dereference to), and for that reason
>   we will always have to cast the
>   address in the void pointer to some
>   other pointer type that points to a
>   concrete data type before
>   dereferencing it.

How could you fix this? Stop using `void*`, basically. Your function is called `compare_int` yet it accepts theoretically any type and attempts to cast it. This is what other commentors / people answering mean when they say "what are you trying to do here?" The `void*` trick is very useful sometimes (for example when you want to be able to use a callback function pointer and let the programmer pass any arguments. `CreateThread` on windows works like this) but here, just for comparing two integers? It's overkill.

Comment: Since the original poster wrote that the code is a snippet  from a large code base, this function is probably meant to be used with `qsort` or a related function, for sorting an `int` array. And for that, the prototype must be exactly this. So one cannot avoid the `void` here.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
int main() {     
   int i = 55;     
   int j = 65;    
   printf("%d\n", 
          compare_int ( &i, &j);   

   return 0;

} 

int compare_int(const void *left, const void *right)
```

would also be a something to consider as well.

Comment: any reasoning for the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I would suspect it's because he has perfectly working code in the first place.